# C# UWP SpeechRecognizer() doesn't inizialize after updating Windows 10 to version 1803

Tags: c#, wpf

I have made a C# WPF app that use microphone and speech recognition (using Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition) and everything worked perfectly for several months till today, **after updating windows 10 from version 1709 to version 1803.**

Infact the SpeechRecognizer() function now is initialized *only* if i change and set the ExecutionLevel to "asInvoker" in my app.manifest file.

The "old" level ("requireAdministrator") now it doesn't work anymore (!?)

Doesn't it sound strange that an administrator cannot initialize anymore the Speechrecognizer?